# php date list for specified duration

Tags: php, date, duration

is there any php classes or functions, which will gives us all the days from specific duration? for example, if i want a list of dates from 25/03/2010 (25th march 2010) to 15/05/2010 (15th May 2010), it will give me:

25/03/2010
26/03/2010
26/03/2010
....
....
....
14/05/2010
15/05/2010

thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$day1 = strtotime ('25/03/2010');
$day2 = strtotime ('15/05/2010');

$oneday = 60 * 60 * 24;

for ($day = $day1; $day <= $day2; $day + $oneday)
{
    echo date ('Y-m-d', $day);
}
```

Should do it.

Comment: I would use '25 March 2010' and '15 May 2010' to avoid problems with european/US date format

Comment: I'd like to beat with a stick whoever though middle-endian dates were a good idea :D

Comment: thanks a lot for the code DCD.. will try it very soon.
and I do agree with u on beating anyone who thought middle-endian dates are good idea ;)

Comment: hmmm DCD i tried the code but it returns 

1970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-011970-01-01197.........................

and it almost made my firefox hang...

Answer (score 2):

It's easy in php5.3 with the new [`DatePeriod`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) objects:

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2010-03-25' );
$end = new DateTime( '2010-05-15 23:59:59' );

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach ( $period as $dt )
  echo $dt->format( "Y-m-d\n " );
```

Comment: my web hosting php is only php 5.2.x.... anyway thanks a lot for the code.. surely will benefit me later